# Correct use of canonical-tag in two shops

Tags: seo, rel-canonical

I have a question regarding canonical-tags where im not pretty sure. I have a main-website and a main-shop and a brand-website with its own shop. The products of one brand are in the brand-shop and in the main shop with mostly the same information. Should i use canonical-tags on the brand-website to show that the origial source is the main-shop? Does this affect seo in a bad way when i have the products on both pages or can i just leave it without a canonical-tag and without any consequences?

Comment: What is the relationship between "main" and "brand"? Are you a business with a branded product, and the product also has its own domain?

Comment: The company has its own website with shop and the brand has its own domain with its own micro-shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you are describing is generating duplicate content across multiple domains.

> Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content
> within or across domains that either completely match other content or
> are appreciably similar. Mostly, this is not deceptive in origin. ([link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en))

Although duplicate content doesn’t cause your site to be penalized, **Google will try to determine the original source of the content and display that one**. It's a better option if we help Google by using the `canonical` tag to select the option we prefer as the main one.

> Let’s put this to bed once and for all, folks: There’s no such thing
> as a “duplicate content penalty.” At least, not in the way most people
> mean when they say that. ([link](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html))